# Color not showing properly in webgrid for different sections

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, grid, webgrid

[image: Attached the screenshot of the webgrid from browser]

I am trying to get the section status colors in the webgrid and divide it percentage wise but it is not working for some of the rows

The webgrid cshtml script for section status is written below.

```
webGrid.Column(header: "Section Status", format: @
    <table class="" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td id="inProgresswd" width="@item.InProgressPC%" title="@item.InProgressPC%"></td>
             <td id="respPendingwd" width="@item.ResponsePendingPC%" title="@item.ResponsePendingPC%"></td>
             <td id="revPendingwd" width="@item.ReviewPendingPC%" title="@item.ReviewPendingPC%"></td>
             <td id="acceptedwd" width="@item.AcceptedPC%" title="@item.AcceptedPC%"></td>
             <td id="rejectedwd" width="@item.RejectedPC%" title="@item.RejectedPC%"></td>
             <td id="ftReciverwd" width="@item.FwdToRecieverPC%" title="@item.FwdToRecieverPC%"></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    , style: "SectionStatus"),
```

The color should be shown in % wise and for zero % the  color should not appear in the grid.As shown the image only 4 status color should appear as 4 have percentage values of 25. But 5 colors are showing up for the highlighted row

Answer (score 0):

`table-layout: fixed` should fix your problem, however sometimes there still is a 1px wide cell if you use the html width attribute instead of css.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

tr > td#inProgresswd {
  background: #faa;
}

tr > td#respPendingwd {
  background: #afa;
}

tr > td#revPendingwd {
  background: #aaf;
}

tr > td#acceptedwd {
  background: #ffa;
}

tr > td#rejectedwd {
  background: #aff;
}

tr > td#ftReciverwd {
  background: #faf;
}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="inProgresswd" width="25%" title="25%"></td>
      <td id="respPendingwd" width="0%" title="0%"></td>
      <td id="revPendingwd" width="0%" title="0%"></td>
      <td id="acceptedwd" width="25%" title="25%"></td>
      <td id="rejectedwd" width="25%" title="25%"></td>
      <td id="ftReciverwd" width="25%" title="25%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br />

<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="inProgresswd" style="width: 25%;" title="25%"></td>
      <td id="respPendingwd" style="width: 0%;" title="0%"></td>
      <td id="revPendingwd" style="width: 0%;" title="0%"></td>
      <td id="acceptedwd" style="width: 25%;" title="25%"></td>
      <td id="rejectedwd" style="width: 25%;" title="25%"></td>
      <td id="ftReciverwd" style="width: 25%;" title="25%"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```